# Percorrendo json usando Ajax jquery

Tags: jquery

Galera tenho uma duvida, como faco para percorrer o Json e recuperar objetos específicos através de ajax?

*Código*:

```
function loadJson(){

$.ajax({
  url: "data.json",
  context: document.body
}).done(function() {
  $( this ).addClass( "done" );
  $(".done").load("data.json");
});
```

}

*Json*:

```
$.json
[  
   {  
      "name":"Rio de janeiro",
      "contents":[  
         {  
            "moment":"Rio de janeiro",
            "gallery":null,
            "tags":[  
               "Calor",
               "Verão",
               "Sol"
            ],
            "text":"ENxuKBLPgIuaevUGsxahYQwggHiheIBHsYxwiAborXeqJRoacSbdkYeufLSdnSiRzUnuVRuKktmBTDltuJXryfKyxXjDrACJXgIU",
            "contentUrl":null,
            "createdAt":1456231430795,
            "type":"TEXT",
            "socialNetwork":"TWITTER",
            "userName":"MatSproesser",
            "avatarUrl":"https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1207792762/opf_normal.jpg"
         },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segue abaixo exemplo comentado

```
$.ajax('data.json').then(function(data) {
    //Converte a string(json) retornada do server para um objeto acessível para o JS
    var meu_json = JSON.parse(data)

    // Printa seu objeto já convertido
    console.log(meu_json);

    // Printa atributo "nome" do seu objeto. Utilize "."(ponto) para acessar os atributos
    console.log(meu_json.nome)

  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Quando você carrega um JSON válido via $.ajax o conteúdo do seu json vai ser transformado em um objeto de javascript, então todas as propriedades do seu JSON vão poder ser acessadas de acordo com o nome de cada propriedade, no código abaixo mostro como acessar o name e as tags:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  $.ajax('data.json').then(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    console.log('name', data.name);
    console.log('tags', data.contents[0].tags);
  });

});
```